# Sudo command (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im trying to make a sudo command but the user i mention in args 0's Profile picture wont show.

```
async execute(client, message, args) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS")) {
            return message.channel.send(`You don't have permission to execute this command.`)}
    message.delete();
    let user =
    message.mentions.members.first() ||
    message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) ||
    message.member.id();
    if (!user) return message.channel.send("Please provide a user!");
    const webhook = await message.channel.createWebhook(user.displayName, {
    avatar: user.user.displayAvatarURL(),
    channel: message.channel.id
    });
    await webhook.send(args.slice(1).join(" ")).then(() => {
    webhook.delete();
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you try logging the value of `user.user.displayAvatarURL()` to the console and show the output? It's possible that it might be giving the wrong thing.

Comment: What is your `user.user.displayAvatarURL()` ? Try changing it to `user.displayAvatarURL()`

Comment: @smallketchup82 How exactly do I do that? ;-;

Said user.displayAvatarURL() is not a function

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. Your declaration of user (`let user =`) is a bit misleading when you are fetching a member object from the cache. I would recommend changing it to member instead for coherency.
2. Smallketchup82 is correct. Because you are getting a member object you would need to use the `.user` attribute to get anything pertaining to the user portion (username, tag, discriminator, and avatar).

If you were to follow the above advice you could do something like:

```js
avatar: member.user.avatarURL()
```

I'm not entirely sure of which method gets the user's avatar as I have only worked with discordjs v13. However, its most likely one of the two:

- `member.user.displayAvatarURL()`
- `member.user.avatarURL()`